Using Expect to make SSH connection in first script, and send commands in another
I have an Expect script which when called successfully connects to a device by ssh. If I want I can even send a command right after connecting. However, my goal is to send mulitple commands from a node.js script (not shown). So I have created a second Expect script to accept the commands and try to send them to the active spawn ID.
However I get the following error when trying to pass the spawn id to teh second script: can

not find channel named "exp5"
while executing

Expect script to make ssh connection:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# ssh_persistent_control.exp

# Suppress the display of the process interaction to terminal
log_user 1

# Get arguments
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set hostname [lindex $argv 2]

#set pipe "/var/www/html/commands/ssh_command_pipe"
set output_pipe "/var/www/html/commands/ssh_command_output_pipe"
set spawnId_pipe "/var/www/html/commands/ssh_spawnId_pipe"
set timeout 5  ; # Adjust as needed

# Global variable to store the spawn_id
set ssh_spawn_id -1

proc open_connection {username password hostname} {
    global ssh_spawn_id output_pipe spawnId_pipe

    if {$ssh_spawn_id != -1} {
        return
    }

    # Create the named pipe if it doesn't exist
    if {![file exists $output_pipe]} {
        exec mkfifo $output_pipe
        exec chmod 666 $output_pipe
    }

    # Open the named pipe for writing
    set pipe_file [open $output_pipe w]

    # Create the named pipe if it doesn't exist
    if {![file exists $spawnId_pipe]} {
        exec mkfifo $spawnId_pipe
        exec chmod 666 $spawnId_pipe
    }

    # Open the named pipe for writing
    set spawnId_pipe_file [open $spawnId_pipe w]

    puts $pipe_file "Attempting to connect...\n"
    
    # Start the SSH connection
    spawn sshpass -p $password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=30 $username@$hostname
    set ssh_spawn_id $spawn_id
    
    # Write the spawn ID to the named pipe
    puts $spawnId_pipe_file $ssh_spawn_id
    close $spawnId_pipe_file


    expect {
        "assword:" {
            send "$password\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "$username@$hostname's password:" {
            send "$password\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "yes/no" {
            send "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Welcome to SSH Server..." {
            puts $pipe_file "Connected successfully. Ready to send commands."
            expect {
                -re {.*?(\r\n|\n)} {
                    set response $expect_out(buffer)
                    puts $pipe_file $response
                    exp_continue  
                }
            }
        }
        timeout {
            send_user "Failed to connect: Timeout while waiting for welcome message.\n"
            puts $pipe_file "Failed to connect: Timeout while waiting for welcome message."
            close $pipe_file
            set ssh_spawn_id -1
            return 0
        }
        eof {
            send_user "Failed to connect: Connection closed unexpectedly.\n"
            puts $pipe_file "Failed to connect: Connection closed unexpectedly."
            close $pipe_file
            set ssh_spawn_id -1
            return 0
        }
    }
}

# Open the connection
open_connection $username $password $hostname



**Expect script to receive command and send it to the ssh spawn id. **
Throws error

can not find channel named "exp5"
while executing

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# send_command.exp

set output_pipe "/var/www/html/commands/ssh_command_output_pipe"

set spawnId_pipe "/var/www/html/commands/ssh_spawnId_pipe"

# Open the spawnId pipe for reading
set spawnId_pipe_file [open $spawnId_pipe r]

# Read the spawn ID
#set spawn_id [gets $spawnId_pipe_file]
set spawn_id [exp_id $spawnId_pipe_file]  ;

# Close the pipe file
close $spawnId_pipe_file

# Create the named pipe if it doesn't exist
    if {![file exists $output_pipe]} {
        exec mkfifo $output_pipe
        exec chmod 666 $output_pipe
    }

    # Open the named pipe for writing
    set pipe_file [open $output_pipe w]

if {$spawn_id == ""} {
    puts $pipe_file "No active SSH session found."
    exit 1
}

# Get the command from the arguments
set command [lindex $argv 0]

if {[string equal $command ""]} {
    puts $pipe_file "No command provided."
    exit 1
}


puts $pipe_file "spawn id is :$spawn_id"

# Send the command to the existing SSH session
send -- "$command\n"

# Read the response
expect {
    -re {.*?(\r\n|\n)} {
        set response $expect_out(buffer)
        puts $pipe_file "Response: $response"
    }
    timeout {
        puts $pipe_file "No response received."
    }
}


What is the proper way to access the spawn id in my case?
I have reference the following similar post answer but still dont understand what I need to change:
how to run expect script on a given spawn id

Your second script doesn't appear to ever call spawn, so expect commands like send and expect naturally won't work.

I really don't think you can usefully send spawn IDs to other processes, as they're abstract handles to a whole bunch of internal state plus who knows how many file descriptors.

when the Expect script exits, the spawned process would be killed so you cannot interact with it any more from another Expect script. you can try my sexpect which implements in a server/client model.
